# pass expression in a variable to [ngClass]

Tags: angular

I want to pass a condition to ngClass and evaluate it, like that:

```
[ngClass]="object.attribute"

where : object.attribute = "{'color-error' : (rowData.x | isLesser :rowData.y)}";
```

When i run my code, ngClass sees the condition as a string so it doesn't evaluate it, it just puts it as a string.

Comment: remove isLesser and try out

Comment: Conditions are written with `||`. If you use `|`, you're asking for a [bitwise operation](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_bitwise.asp). And if you want to use a pipe, you can't use it in string variables. Pipes need to be compiled, and strings aren't compiled.

Comment: i tried it without the pipe but it always sees it as a string, it is not evaluated

Answer (score 0):

you can use NgClass like this:

```
<some-element [ngClass]="'first second'">...</some-element>

<some-element [ngClass]="['first', 'second']">...</some-element>

<some-element [ngClass]="{'first': true, 'second': true, 'third': false}">...</some-element>

<some-element [ngClass]="stringExp|arrayExp|objExp">...</some-element>

<some-element [ngClass]="{'class1 class2 class3' : true}">...</some-element>
```

You can see here [Angular NgClass](https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass) Documentation.

Comment: Can i use class attribute then ?     class="object.attribute"   where object.attribute = "{{(rowData.x > rowData.y ) ? 'color-error' :  ' ' }}"

Answer (score 0):

Use need to use || operator

```
<div [ngClass]="{'color-error' : (rowData.x || rowData.y)}"></div>
```